# Add tag to Heading and converter to tag inside List item with plugin responsiveTab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm using ( http://www.petelove.com/responsiveTabs/ )

and i'm try to add a HTML to list when it's load, but it's working Could someone tell me how can do that.

now when add heading, it's converter to tabs,

but i want to add tag inside heading and converter to tag inside list item but not work.

```html
<pre>
    this plugin use HTML like that : 
    <div class="responsive-tabs"> 
        <h2>[...]</h2> 
        <div>[...]</div> 
        <h2>[...]</h2> 
        <div>[...]</div> 
    </div>
    ** then it's will converter to : **
    <div class="responsive-tabs"> 
        <ul> 
            <li>[content of heading]</li> 
            <li>[content of heading]</li> 
        </ul> 
        <div>[...]</div> 
        <div>[...]</div> 
    </div> 
    and i don't want to be like that, i want to be link this example : 
    <div class="responsive-tabs"> 
        <ul> 
            <li><span>[content of heading]</span></li> 
            <li><span>[content of heading]</span></li> 
        </ul> 
        <div>[...]</div> 
        <div>[...]</div> 
    </div>
</pre>
```

Need some help.

cheers.

Comment: If want me to add example, let me know will do it.

Comment: yes. an example will almost certainly be needed.

Comment: ok,
what i want its :
this plugin use HTML like that :
<div class="responsive-tabs">
  <h2>[...]</h2>
  <div>[...]</div>
  <h2>[...]</h2>
  <div>[...]</div>
</div>
then it's will converter to 
<div class="responsive-tabs">
     <ul>
          <li>[...]</li>
          <li>[...]</li>
    </ul>
  <div>[...]</div>

  <div>[...]</div>
</div>
and i don't want to be like that, i want to be link this example :

<div class="responsive-tabs">
     <ul>
          <li><span>[...]</span></li>
          <li><span>[...]</span></li>
    </ul>
  <div>[...]</div>

  <div>[...]</div>
</div>

Comment: Sorry didn't know how to edit question and i explain at comment below what i want.

Comment: Please edit the original question (the edit link is below the body of your question). The last thing anybody wants is to try to read html in a comment.

Comment: Hey, i have did, could be check it please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I've found the solution by  editing the plugin Code**

```js
var $tabListItem = $('<li/>', { 
    'class': 'responsive-tabs__list__item',
 id: 'tablist' + tablistcount + '-tab' + tabcount,
 'aria-controls': 'tablist' + tablistcount +'-panel' + tabcount,
 'role': 'tab',
    tabindex: 0,
 text: $tabHeading.text() ,
    keydown: function (objEvent) {
  if (objEvent.keyCode === 13) { // if user presses 'enter'
  $tabListItem.click();
 }
},...
```

And i changed to  be line this :

```js
var $tabListItem = $('<li/>', { 
    'class': 'responsive-tabs__list__item',
 id: 'tablist' + tablistcount + '-tab' + tabcount,
 'aria-controls': 'tablist' + tablistcount +'-panel' + tabcount,
 'role': 'tab',
    tabindex: 0,
 html: $tabHeading.html() ,
    keydown: function (objEvent) {
  if (objEvent.keyCode === 13) { // if user presses 'enter'
  $tabListItem.click();
 }
},...
```

then it's give tag Span i was use inside heading at HTML LIST code.

Thanks for communication.